# Installing PyQt for maya in windows 10

Tags: windows, pyqt, maya

Does anyone know how to install PyQt for maya in windows 10? I've looked around online and there's no clear enough tutorial on how to do so. I just haven't been able to understand how to go about installing it as the steps in any tutorial are not detailed enough. May be just me, though who can't figure it out. So I'm hoping someone could guide me or if there's an install PyQt for Maya in Windows 10 for dummies version available online?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Maya?

Comment: I'm trying it on Maya 2017

Comment: you could just use PySide (maya 2016 and before) or PySide2 (for everything after)... It's pre-installed with maya and is almost identical to PyQt with very minor differences that are described in Maya's online help docs.

Comment: If you desperately need pyqt, you could have a look here: http://around-the-corner.typepad.com/adn/2017/06/how-to-build-pyqt5-for-autodesk-maya-2017-64bit.html but it is a bit complicated. I recommend as to use PySide2 as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: @haggikrey I did try that link, and yes it is a bit complicated and I didn't succeed.

Comment: @silent_night awesome I'll give that a go then if they're pretty much the same, I'll just have to figure out the difference as my office uses PyQt instead of PySide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this might help http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_3F96AF53_A47E_4351_A86A_396E7BFD6665_htm